# How does this cause absolute silence?

Tags: javascript

```js
var l = {
  install: function(v, s, G) {
    window[v] = function(m) {
      console.log(m, this.s, this.G);
    }
    window[v].v = v;
    window[v].s = s;
    window[v].G = G;
    return;
  }
};

l.install('xx5', '11', {
  a: 4
});

xx5('i hope this works');
//undefined

window.xx5('?');
//undefined
```

I am wondering why there is no error or log

I don't want to know alternative solutions **I am confused only because the xx5() funtion seems to fire but does not log and because there is no error**

How does this cause absolute silence?

I am expecting to see:

```
'i hope this works' 11 {a:4}

'?' 11 {a:4}
```

Comment: I don't know about you, but "Uncaught ReferenceError: v is not defined" doesn't look like "no error or log" to me.

Comment: What browser are you using to run this code?

Comment: i had window[v].v = v; part in there then removed it while editing the question I really am getting brain fried sorry

Comment: in brave it does not show any message undefined undefined. It only shows 1 undefined

Comment: In Chrome I get two log messages: `i hope this works undefined undefined` and `? undefined undefined`

Comment: After your edit the statement `xx5() funtion seems to fire but does not log` and the title `How does this cause absolute silence?` are  wrong, because now it logs something in the console.

Comment: When you call the function, `this` is the global object, not the `window[v]` function. So logging `this.s` and `this.G` shows `window.s` and `window.G`. These are both undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever properties you have attached `s` , `v` , `G` are attached on the `window['xx5']`.

When you are running you functions :

```
xx5('i hope this works'); // No object, so `this` belongs to the window object

window.xx5('?'); //Attached to the window object, so once again `this` belongs to the window object
```

When you look for `this.s`, you are looking for `window.s`. Which obviously will be `undefined`.

You can do this to get your expected output:

```js
var l = {
  install: function(v, s, G) {
    window[v] = function(m) {
      console.log(m, this[v].s, this[v].G);
    }
    window[v].v = v;
    window[v].s = s;
    window[v].G = G;
    return;
  }
};

l.install('xx5', '11', {
  a: 4
});

xx5('i hope this works');
//undefined

window.xx5('?');
//undefined
```